# Visual Studio 2019 import of WSDL with operation names containing UTF-8 chars

Tags: c#, xml, soap, wsdl, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to import a WSDL filen into Visual Studio 2019 V16.6.3 (using Add Service Reference) without success.

It seems that the problem is, that some of the operation tags contains UTF-8 chars. Like this one:

> <wsdl:operation name="EnØvelse"> ... </wsdl:operation>

The WSDL importer in VS shows '??' instead of the char 'Ø' from the name attriibute. None of the operations are imported.

The WSDL file is tagged with 'encoding="UTF-8"' and the file itself is in UTF-8.

Testing this WSDL in SoapUI show no errors.

Any suggestions as to how I fix this?

Comment: The issue is with the viewer you are using to look at the results and not anything in the code.  One byte character are from 0x00 to 0xFF.  The characters from 0x00 to 0x80 are the same for all encoding methods.  To avoid using two byte character which take up more memory encoding maps the characters from 0x80 to 0xFF with two bytes characters saving one byte.  Your viewer has to be set the same as the encoding to be able to see all the character properly.  The two question marks just indicate the viewer you are using is different from the encoding of the characters.

Comment: I am using the build-in WSDL import tool in VS 2019, and that is where I see the ??. The tool also writes to the VS 2019 error window, that the WSDL contains invalid chars hence it cannot generate a class file for me.

Do you know where to change the encoding you are writing about?

Comment: The tool is probably opening a console window and the console encoding does not match the encoding in the xml.  If you console is set to USA English which does not contain 'Ø' you will see a different character.